# Decomposing regular polygons into other regular polygons

Tags: geometry

I came across the german Wikipedia page for the Dodecagon and there it said (my translation) "The regular Hexagon and the regular Dodecagon are the only regular polygons that can be decomposed into smaller regular polygons".

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zw%C3%B6lfeck#Zerlegung_in_regelm%C3%A4%C3%9Fige_Polygone

I object to that as both the equilateral triangle and the square can be decomposed into four smaller copies of themselves.

I believe what the article wants to say is "...into regular polygons with fewer sides".

Is that a better way of phrasing it? Is the fact correct at all? Can someone give me a citation for it? How would one go about proving this?

Regards, Marian

Comment: I agree with your concerns about the German "kleinere". Perhaps the author intended it to mean fewer sides, not simply physically smaller, and didn't realise the ambiguity.

Comment: Place it in context.  They say ""kleineren Zahl von Ecken", which translates literally as "smaller numbers of corners".  No I am not that good at German, I had an "English" option when I clicked the link.

Comment: @Oscar - Your translation is correct. It mentions Ecken/corners now after I have taken the liberty of making it a bit more precise. The fact that my edit passed review makes me believe that that may indeed be what was intended.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting additional example can be found in spherical geometry.  On a sphere, a properly sized regular pentagon can be divided into five equilateral triangles. Simply inscribe a regular icosahedron in the sphere and use the contact points to define the vertices of the pentagon and its component triangles.